# Correct way to write unit test for generic method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

We have this code

```
public class Service<T, E>{
 
  private final Class<T> domainClass;
  
  private final Class<E> entityClass;
  
  private final Repository<E> repository;
 
  private final AnotherService conversionService;
  @Override
  public ResponseDto deleteAllThenImportAll(Collection<T> data) {
    Collection<E> entities = conversionService.convert(data, domainClass, entityClass);
    ResponseEntity entity = repository.deleteAllThenImportAll(entities);
    return conversionService.convert(entity);
  }
}
```

How to create unit tests without creating specific types for generic

Comment: Generics are checked at compile time. If it works for one type, it will work for other types (generally speaking). What is your current test and what exactly do you want to avoid? Note that your code currently does not compile, because the private final fields are never initialized.

Comment: You cannot. In order to test this class, you need to instantiate it. This cannot be done without explicit types. What you could do is mock all interactions with conversionServiceService and repository - in this way, the types of entites do not really matter. But IMHO you may get more value with testing with real classes, maybe even all pairs of domainClass-entityClass you expect.

Comment: Okay, I get it.  thank you!